# How to determine an android phones viewing direction when starting an app

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an Augmented Reality app for Android without tracking images/objects. The user stands at a predefined position and virtual objects are placed into the real world. when the user turns around or moves the phone, the objects are fixed at their respective places. I do this by applying the gyroscope data to the camera.

My problem: I want the objects positions to be always fixed to the same places regardless of the users viewing direction when he starts up the app. Right now, on starting the app, the objects are positioned depending on the camera. After that, they are fixed to their places, when the user changes his viewing direction.

I drew an image of what the exact problem is to better elaborate:
[image: user viewing direction image]

I want to know which sensors are relevant to solve this problem. Since Google Maps accurately determines the viewing direction of a user, I assume there are built in sensors to find out in which direction the user is looking in order to apply this information to the camera's rotation at the start.

This is the code I use to apply the phones rotation to the camera (I'm using Unity and C#):

```js
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gyrotransform : MonoBehaviour
{
    // STATE
    private float _initialYAngle = 0f;
    private float _appliedGyroYAngle = 0f;
    private float _calibrationYAngle = 0f;
    private Transform _rawGyroRotation;
    private float _tempSmoothing;

    // SETTINGS
    [SerializeField] private float _smoothing = 0.1f;

    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
        _initialYAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;

        _rawGyroRotation = new GameObject("GyroRaw").transform;
       // _rawGyroRotation.parent = Core.Instance.transform;
        _rawGyroRotation.position = transform.position;
        _rawGyroRotation.rotation = transform.rotation;

        // Wait until gyro is active, then calibrate to reset starting rotation.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        StartCoroutine(CalibrateYAngle());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ApplyGyroRotation();
        ApplyCalibration();

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, _rawGyroRotation.rotation, _smoothing);
    }

    private IEnumerator CalibrateYAngle()
    {
        _tempSmoothing = _smoothing;
        _smoothing = 1;
        _calibrationYAngle = _appliedGyroYAngle - _initialYAngle; // Offsets the y angle in case it wasn't 0 at edit time.
        yield return null;
        _smoothing = _tempSmoothing;
    }

    private void ApplyGyroRotation()
    {
        _rawGyroRotation.rotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
        _rawGyroRotation.Rotate(0f, 0f, 180f, Space.Self); // Swap "handedness" of quaternion from gyro.
        _rawGyroRotation.Rotate(90f, 180f, 0f, Space.World); // Rotate to make sense as a camera pointing out the back of your device.
        _appliedGyroYAngle = _rawGyroRotation.eulerAngles.y; // Save the angle around y axis for use in calibration.
    }

    private void ApplyCalibration()
    {
        _rawGyroRotation.Rotate(0f, -_calibrationYAngle, 0f, Space.World); // Rotates y angle back however much it deviated when calibrationYAngle was saved.
    }

    public void SetEnabled(bool value)
    {
        enabled = true;
        StartCoroutine(CalibrateYAngle());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it the `Gyroskope` returns the rotational difference since it was started.

That's why your objects appear in the direction you are facing during start.

---

I guess what you rather want might be [Compass.magneticHeading](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass-magneticHeading.html) at least for setting the correct rotation once at gamestart

```
 // Orient an object to point to magnetic north.
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -Input.compass.magneticHeading, 0);
```

You could do this once at start on the parent of all the objects you want to show in order to orient them correctly on the GPS north.